# Надо ли обособлять запятыми слово "практически"?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: "Я являюсь членом Клуба **практически** с его основания".

Answer (score 2):

Причин для постановки запятой нет. Слово **практически** является наречием.

ПРАКТИЧЕСКИ, нареч. 1. В практическом отношении, на практике (1-2 зн.). Идея исследована п. и теоретически. Осуществить замысел п. П. решить проблему. Ознакомиться с материалами п. 2. По существу, по сути дела. Работа п. завершена. Собрались п. все. П. всё осталось по-прежнему. П. оба проекта не годны.